# Настройка ULOGD

Tags: iptables

Настройка ULOGD, сейчас выводит кучу не нужной информации, но можно ли чтобы выводил только ip адрес и все? Не нашел где можно настроить вывод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно раскоментить строку plugin="/usr/lib/ulogd/ulogd_OPRINT.so" в файле /etc/ulogd.conf, и поставить в этом же файле уровень debug (loglevel=1), тогда в файл который указан в настройках плагина OPRINT будет писаться инфа построчно, типа

`ip.fragoff=16384ip.id=7766ip.csum=7788ip.ihl=5ip.totlen=52ip.ttl=64ip.tos=0ip.protocol=6ip.daddr=127.0.0.1ip.saddr=127.0.0.1`

Ну а дальше грепать по полую ip.saddr или daddr. Только не забывайте про размер файла.

Answer (score 1):

[ulogd](http://rlworkman.net/howtos/ulogd.html) там есть чтото про фильтры, но не пользовался им...

еще [примеры](http://www.opennet.ru/base/net/ulog_traf.txt.html)